# Auto Import on Vim Coc-tsserver using Next.js

Tags: vim, next.js, eslint, neovim, typescript-eslint

I'm using coc-tsserver on Neovim to program with Next.js, but the Auto Import feature is not working. When I try use a Next module, for example the `<Link>` tag, it recognizes the `"import Link from 'next/link'"` with no errors, but it's not able to find the module when the import line is missing. I already tried to config tsserver to use the external Eslint package, but it's still not working (even the yarn Eslint package is not able to find next modules when it's not specified).
How can I auto import Next.js modules on Eslint/coc-tsserver?

Answer (score 5):

From the tsserver documentation
https://github.com/neoclide/coc-tsserver

you may need to  add code below to your coc-config

```
"javascript.suggest.autoImports": true, 
"typescript.suggest.autoImports": true
```

with `:CocConfig`